# Number of ways to pack $d$-dimensional hypercubes into an $n$-dimensional hypercube

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $Q_n$ denote the $n$-dimensional hypercube graph. I am interested in counting the number of ways to partition $Q_n$ into $2^{n-d}$ vertex-disjoint copies of $Q_d$, for some integer parameter $1 \leq d \leq n$.

For example, when $n = 2$ and $d=1$, then the answer should be 2. We label the vertices of $Q_2$ by $\{00, 01, 10, 11\}$. Then we can partition $Q_2$ as $\{00, 01\}$ and $\{10, 11\}$, which are two vertex disjoint copies of $Q_1$. Alternatively, the partition $\{00, 10\}$ and $\{01, 11\}$ is also valid for the same reason -- hence giving the answer of 2.

Is there a way to establish a recurrence for this problem in terms of $n$ and $d$ perhaps?

Comment: Easy cases: $n$ ways when $d = n-1$. One way when $d=0$.  Maybe work out $d=n-2$ for small $n$ and check OEIS.

Comment: Judging by this OEIS entry, it seems the case $d=1$ is open. https://oeis.org/A005271

Comment: @MikeEarnest I'm a bit confused. How is the $d=1$ case the same as counting perfect matchings? For $n=3$, the answer in the provided OEIS link is 9, but I would count 12 such partitions.

Comment: I count $9$ partitions: $3$ partitions where the $Q_2$'s all have the same orientation, and $6$ others. If you are counting how I think you are counting ($3$ ways to choose an axis (say, $x$), $2$ ways to tile the $x=0$ plane, $2$ ways to tile the $x=1$ plane), then you are double counting some partitions.

Comment: Ah, you are right! I see where I went wrong now. Then it would seem like the problem is open after all. I'll have a closer look at the OEIS link and the references therein. Thanks!